# Do universal apps mean that the download size is larger than needed for iPhone and iPod devices?

Tags: ios

Including @2X and ~ipad graphics in an app I am working on increases the app size by eight megabytes.  This, along with other graphics that have to be done in triplicate makes apps in general grow very quickly.

I am wondering what happens when someone downloads a universal app onto, say, an iPod touch.  Do they get the entire package, including @2X and ~ipad images that they, effectively, won't use or does Apple repackage the application to only send relevant graphics?

If it's option #2, are there any dangers in trying to save some space by using code to apply @2X images to the iPad version of an app.  After all, in most cases @2X and ~ipad assets are so close in size that it makes little sense to duplicate files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users will download the same binary if your app is universal. Apple can't repackage the application because it can't tell if the developer wanted to use an ~iPad asset when running on the iPhone for example. Also, users can download the app from iTunes and sync both an iPad and an iPhone.

Comment: This is what I suspected.  Just wanted to be sure.  I hadn't thought of the iTunes download possibility because I never go that route and don't think I know anyone who does.

Answer (score 3):

Download size will be larger for everyone. Whole package will be downloaded all the time.

You can use @2x graphics for iPad by stating the full name of the image, *including* `@2x`.

I would advise against it, though. They are not of the same size, and some resize-on-display can impair your quality, and sometimes speed.
If you grow too much, maybe you should just separate universal app into 2 targeted ones.

You also need to make sure you look at the resulting IPA files, not zipped folder of your project or something similar. Xcode compresses PNG images before packaging (using `pngcrush`), and poorly optimised images can be reduced in size up to 2 times and more. Your App Store size will be roughly same as release-version IPA.

Then again, maybe something is worth to be converted to high-quality JPEG rather than keep too detailed PNGs.

Comment: As it turns out, for this particular app we decided to use a single high-resolution set of images loaded in code into UIImageView's.  Works fine across all devices and resolutions.  The best side effect is that you end-up with a universal app that isn't three or four times larger due to the duplication of assets.

Comment: Your solution is nice from size point of view, but will probably impact speed for all devices and memory for older pre-retina iPhones and iPods.

Comment: We tested all the way back to iPod Touch v2 and there are no issues with usability.  So, moving forward with this approach as of now.

Comment: I'd recommend using [pngquant](http://pngmini.com) instead of relying on Xcode, [since that can halve the size and double loading speed compared to Xcode-optimized images](http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html)